# Laravel mix with PHP helpers

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-mix

In my homepage I have defined a section to forward variables to JS side in a way that I call PHP helper methods, for example:

```
<script>
    var base_url = "{{ url('/') }}";
</script>
```

This works within blade template, however if I put that to a script and try to minify through Laravel mix, it just gets compressed as a string literal. How could I force resolving this before somehow? Or keep it working within a minified file?

Comment: Laravel mix is pure javascript, it doesn't execute any of the php code because that's not how it works.

The best you could do is attach your `base_url` variable to the `window` and use it in that way in your scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#environment-variables) we may inject environment variables into `Mix` by prefixing a key in your `.env` file with `MIX_` After the variable has been defined in your `.env` file, you may access via the `process.env` object. if you using Vue you can use [This Package](https://github.com/websanova/vue-env) A Simple plugin for loading an environment file.